# Why is the past tense used here instead of the present?

Tags: meaning-in-context, tense, past-tense, present-tense

Let me talk about this sentence.

A girl is currently married to a cricketer of another country. When a reporter asked someone about her, he would have said that "she has married that country's cricketer, hence she is no more of our country now. She is a daughter-in-law of Pakistan."

But while reporting this in a newspaper, the reporter wrote:

> Sania was born in Maharashtra and settled in Hyderabad only later and, hence, is a "non-local", he told reporters here and sought to dub her as "daughter-in-law" of Pakistan, pointing out that she **was** married to that country's cricketer Shoaib Malik.

My question is why has the author used past simple tense in this? Why didn’t he use "is" instead of "was"?

Reference link:

http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/Pakistans-daughter-in-law-Sania-Mirza-lacks-credentials-to-be-Telangana-brand-ambassador-BJP/articleshow/38965740.cms

Comment: Please quote the original sentence and provide a link or reference to the source.

Comment: It's not clear what in your sentence is an actual quotation, and what is a paraphrase. I suggest you revise the question to include the full quotation that confused you and remove quotation marks around anything that is not a direct quote. Without the full quote, issues like subject-verb agreement are difficult to evaluate.

Comment: Please refer my question again. I have put referance news and link. Plz reply

Comment: Good job adding more context and a link to the article, this question has improved a lot.

Answer (score 2):

They use the past tense because in reporting or retelling things, we retain the tense of the reporting verb in the account reported:

> She assures me she **knows** Russian.

Here the reporting verb is in the present - assures, so the the same tense is used for "knows."

> She assured me that she **knew** Russian.

Here "assured" is a past form, so "knew" is preferred. Similarly, in your story, everything is told in the past tense, so "was married" is used instead of "is married."